# Capital Vowel: Inclusion of variable makes If statement behave strangely

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've been trying my hand at some coderbyte problems where I came across the Capital Vowel Problem. When I include the variable "matchTheChar" in my if-statement the code gives me a strange value

```
function VowelCount(str) { 
  var results=0;
  var str=str.toLowerCase();
  var matchTheChar= str.charAt(i);
  myRegExp=/[aeiou]/;
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (myRegExp.test(matchTheChar)){
      results=results+1;
    }

  }  
  return results; 

}
```

However when I remove the variable and include the "str.charAt(i)" straight into the if-statement, the code works fine.

```
function VowelCount(str) { 
      var results=0;
      var str=str.toLowerCase();
      //var matchTheChar= str.charAt(i);
      myRegExp=/[aeiou]/;
      for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if (myRegExp.test(str.charAt(i))){
          results= results+1;
        }

      }  
      return results; 

    }
```

Why is this happening to the code?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have your

```
var matchTheChar= str.charAt(i);
```

**before** you assign any value to `i`, and outside the loop. That means it's basically:

```
var matchTheChar= str.charAt(undefined);
```

...which will give you the first character*. And then you'll repeatedly test that first character in the loop, because you're never assigning a new value to `matchTheChar`.

Just set `matchTheChar` *inside* the loop:

```
function VowelCount(str) { 
  var results=0;
  var str=str.toLowerCase();
  var matchTheChar;
  myRegExp=/[aeiou]/;
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    matchTheChar= str.charAt(i);       // <===
    if (myRegExp.test(matchTheChar)){
      results=results+1;
    }

  }  
  return results; 
}
```

---

* Why does it return the first character? Because `charAt` passes its argument through the specification operation [`ToInteger`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tointeger), which converts it via `ToNumber` and gets `NaN`, which it then treats as 0.

---

Side note: There are several other things to fix in there:

- Unless you've defined `myRegExp` somewhere you haven't shown, your code is alling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Be sure to declare your variables before using them.
- You're receiving `str` as an argument, and so shouldn't use `var str` to declare it as a local variable. (It happens not to matter, but it's still a bad idea.)
- `results=results+1;` is just fine, but note that you can also use `++results;` or `results++;` or `results += 1;`.

Comment: Awesome answer. Also thanks for the extra advice on my code, will implement accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code snippet, you're only running `str.charAt(i)` once, and `i` at this point is undefined.  In your second snippet, you're calling it once per character inside your loop.